# Passing Jboss JNDI db connection to Jasper Sub Report Causing Deadlock

Tags: java, jasper-reports, db2, jndi, dbconnection

I need to pass database connection object to jasper report as

```
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,
            parameterMap, connection);
output = new FileOutputStream(new File(reportPath + ".pdf"));
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, output);
```

The issue when i use JBoss JNDI datasource, it throwsfollowing exception

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-913, SQLSTATE=57033, SQLERRMC=00C9008E;00000302;TLINEUPS.LUPPDSDV.X'000B27'
```

Technology Used DB2 9, Spring Batch, Jasper Report, JBoss EAP 6.4

I am getting connection from as below

```
Connection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = transactionManager.getDataSource().getConnection();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.error(e.fillInStackTrace());
}
```

Appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31063300/java-db2-error-sqlcode-913-sqlstate-57003-sqlerrmc-schema-table-table-driver,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13871326/deadlock-in-a-springhibernatedb2jtaxa-application, http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21386398

Comment: Since it for report, check if you can get connection in read only mode...

Comment: thanks for reply. tomorrow i will give a try and let you know

Comment: Judging by the error code, you are connecting to DB2 fo z/OS, and `SQLERRMC=00C9008E` indicates a lock timeout. A read-only connection may or may not resolve the problem.

Comment: @PetterFriberg  i have tried connection with readonly mode. But still issue is there.

Comment: You have the issue in subreport not in main report?, can you change lock type of table (row-level locking)?

Comment: @PetterFriberg Thanks its working now when i change the lock type of table to row-level locking